# bad Shading around the border of a mesh with shrinkwrap modifier

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I have a mesh shrinkwrapped onto another mesh, but where I have the arrows, I'm seeing a little bit of shading.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use this topology, it works not too bad:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please do a small GIF Animation how you made that topology?

Comment: I'm bevelling the corners and getting an incorrect result: https://ibb.co/ZmfDLqn

Comment: ok, I've edited my answer, I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks 1000 times!!!